# caching decorator

Tags: python, meta-programming, memoization

I came up with a caching decorator for pure functions. Is it ok? Could it be better/simpler/faster?

```
def cached(f):    
    def _(*args):
        if args in _._cache:
            return _._cache[args]
        else:
            result = f(*args)
            _._cache[args] = result
            return result     
    _._cache = {}
    return _
```

Comment: I mean, not an improvement or anything, but they do have a `lru_cache` function already built into the library. I would suspect it to be faster than this... In other words, if this is part of a bigger scheme I would consider using `lru_cache` instead.

Comment: @Dair It might not be available to everyone since `lru_cache` has only been added in Python 3.2.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: Good point. I still think he should be aware, especially since he hasn't specified his python version.

Comment: @Dair Yes, it's just that, [by the look of things](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/119590/84718), he seems to be using Python 2. But your point remains valid anyway.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6 and LRU cache as I understand it stores only a limited set of latest used results and I need a full cache.

Comment: @Eugene: you can specify maxsize=None for arbitrary amount of storage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called memoization and has already a number of [recipe available on the Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).

Your implementation matches the one using nested functions:

> ```
> # note that this decorator ignores **kwargs
> def memoize(obj):
>     cache = obj.cache = {}
>
>     @functools.wraps(obj)
>     def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
>         if args not in cache:
>             cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
>         return cache[args]
>     return memoizer
> ```

A few things to note here on top of yours:

- usage of a local variable which resolves faster than an attribute lookup
- usage of `functools.wraps` which keeps some properties of the original function intact (name and docstring, mainly)
- explicit names for variables

Comment: What you mean by explicit names for variables?

Comment: @Eugene `_` has no meaning; `memoizer` has an explicit name which convey meaning.